# Meaning of square brackets in Euler's summation formula

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, notation

I am working my way through Apostol's text on number theory.

Euler's summation formula is given as:

$$
\sum_{y < n \leq x}f(n) = \int_y^x f(t)dt + \int_y^x(t-[t])f'(t)dt + f(x)([x] - x) - f(y)([y] - y)
$$

My question is, what is the meaning of the square bracket notation?

Comment: I'm guessing $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$. That's the usual meaning, but wouldn't know about the specific formula.

Comment: so like the floor function?

Comment: Yep, that's another name for it.

Comment: yeah that works out. If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[x]$ should stand for the integer part (or floor function) of $x$.